# Any standard function to code complex identifier for using it the html element id/class/name?

Tags: javascript, html

Do we have any preferred/standard way to "encode" complex identifiers e.g {Source:"ARCH.1", Code: "456-789.456 A+", SubNumber:##2} for using in HTML elements id, class, name attributes? 
I can invent something, but may be there is universal well know solution that is:

1. stable
2. is ease to decode
3. generates tokens that are still readable and is easy to use in css
   selectors

Comment: What happens if two different complex identifiers "encode" to the same friendly identifier (much like how two or more strings could have the same MD5 checksum)? Does that make the solution not stable?

Comment: Instead of trying to find a one-size-fits-all solution, consider writing one that's tailored to your system of identifiers for best results. A universal solution is almost certainly going to give you results that are anything *but* readable or easy to use in selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I think your question is...you may be mixing concerns and creating extra dependencies. With your approach, if the data changes form, you may need to change your JS and CSS too or you will face a broken design. I don't think you want that.

If you need an identifier in the HTML for a data hook (for AJAX calls), there are `data-` attributes that may be used, but I would not recommend using a combination of these as a hook to styling. Instead, I would stick to classes.